# how i split delimited string value into rows and join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Table like this:

---

TABLE 1(ANSWERS)

```
|     ID         | CODE_STUDENT| ANSWERS
+----------------+-------------+-------------------
| 1              | 1           | 1,2,4
| 2              | 2           | 3,2,3
```

---

TABLE 2(STUDENT)

```
|     ID         | NAME        | GENDER
+----------------+-------------+-------------------
| 1              | ANDY        | MAN
| 2              | MARRY       | WOMAN
```

how do I get the select query results like this

```
| STUDENT.ID     | STUDENT.NAME| QUESTION          | ANSWERS.ANSWERS
+----------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------
| 1              | ANDY        | 1                 | 1
| 1              | ANDY        | 2                 | 2
| 1              | ANDY        | 3                 | 4
| 2              | MARRY       | 1                 | 3
| 2              | MARRY       | 2                 | 2
| 2              | MARRY       | 3                 | 3
```

Basically split my data at the comma into individual rows and join two table?

---

the question values, can be obtained by counting the number of indexes of the answers

Comment: There's no standard SQL function for this because *you aren't supposed to store multiple values in a table cell*. That violates the most basic design rule. Different databases have different functions for this

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server ... which one are you actually using?

Comment: Can you share your QUESTION table as well?

Comment: The real solution is to use *multiple rows* per answer. The `Answers` table isn't really an Answers table, it's a M-N StudentAnswers table. The `AnswerID` deserves to be a column of its own, with a FK to the actual `Answers` table. This will allow you to guard against *duplicate answers*

Comment: With properly designed tables, getting all student questions and answers would be as simple as `select S.ID,s.Name,a.QuestionID, a.ID as AnswerID  from student s inner join StudentAnswers sa on s.ID=sa.CODE_Student inner join Answers a on sa.ID=a.ID`

Comment: You can Use Below Query -
SELECT CODE_STUDENT AS STUDENT_ID,NAME AS STUDENT_NAME,QUESTION,Answer   FROM 
(
SELECT ANS_ID,CODE_STUDENT,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'),'-','.'),1) 'Answer' ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE_STUDENT ORDER BY CODE_STUDENT) AS QUESTION
FROM  
(
     SELECT ANS_ID,CODE_STUDENT,
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(ANS_NO, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
     FROM ANSWERS     
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)temp_ANS
INNER JOIN STUDENT ON temp_ANS.CODE_STUDENT = STUDENT.ST_ID